# php fail to find the string "id()"

Tags: php, string

i have 2 strings:

```
$str1 = "pe vra$.acstask.** cl(facility) id() acc(read)";
$str2 = "pe vra$.acstask.** cl(facility) id() acc(read)";
```

1) when i run

```
str_replace("<" , "< " , $str1);
```

i get

```
pe vra$.acstask.** cl(facility) id(< audtaudt>) acc(read)
```

and when i run

```
str_replace("<" , "< " , $str2);
```

i get

```
pe vra$.acstask.** cl(facility) id(< secaaudt>) acc(read)
```

2) so i tried to run strpos on both strings like

```
strpos($str1, "id()")
```

or

```
strpos($str2, "id()")
```

and the string is NOT found.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It looks as though your content may actually be something like `id(<audtaudt>)`, if you are viewing this in a browser it may be trying to use the middle bit as HTML.  Check it by viewing the source code of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
strpos($str1, "id(")
or
strpos($str2, "id(")